# Property '' does not exist on type '' - despite having interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a class component. I made an interface for the class, but am getting the error `Property '' does not exist on type ''`  on my `scrollDiv` property. What was missed in the composition of this class?

```
 interface ChatTabI {
  state: any;
  scrollDiv: any;
  history: any;
  user: any;
}
class ChatTab extends React.Component<ChatTabI> {
// @ts-ignore

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        text: "",
        messages: [],
        loading: false,
        channel: null,
    };

    this.scrollDiv = React.createRef();

 }
...
}
```

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: Doesn't `ChatTabI` define the **props** type?

Comment: yes it does define the props type, and this isn't props, but i still don't know why there is a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.scrollDiv` You are accessing the class property with this line.

So you would need to do something like this.

```
 interface ChatTabI {
  state: any;
  scrollDiv: any;
  history: any;
  user: any;
}
class ChatTab extends React.Component<ChatTabI> {

  scrollDiv: any; // or whatever this type would be

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        text: "",
        messages: [],
        loading: false,
        channel: null,
    };

    this.scrollDiv = React.createRef();

 }
...
}
```